# how to get admin details in front end in magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, admin, shipping-methods

I want to display shipping method for particular admin user,
 in the checkout page, i tried to get admin user details in front end,
 and i followed some of the things but it always returns a null value.

> Magento\User\Model\UserFactory $userFactory

Comment: tbh Im not sure what exactly You want to do. Get shipping meethods for admin user on frontend? How, where?

Comment: Don't forget to set `store_code` to `admin` before requesting yours shipping methods

Comment: if admin login as customer and place order want to show free shipping method for that trying to access admin details...

Comment: @Nolwennig can you explain me what is the store_code and where i need to set??and also benefits of this??

Comment: @ravichandra see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34765142/4457531

Answer (score 1):

try with below code to get admin details.

```
$adminuserId = 15;
$user = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(
'Magento\User\Model\User');
$user->load($adminuserId);
```